# Encountered an error while attempting to update latest block (error code 1020 on Polygon mainnet)

Tags: contract-development, truffle, truffle-migration, error

I'm trying to migrate a smart contract on Polygon (Matic) mainnet through truffle, but I get the following error:

```
node_modules\@trufflesuite\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\rpc.js:57
          const err = new Error(msg)
                      ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
Error: Unknown Error: error code: 1020
    at Request._callback (node_modules\@trufflesuite\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\rpc.js:57:23)
    at Request.self.callback (node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1223:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (node_modules\eth-block-tracker\src\polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I tried it with at least five different providers (https and wss), but the result is the same. I could not find anything about error code 1020 which I'm facing. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like [CloudFlare Access Denied](https://webpop.io/cloudflare/error-1020-access-denied/), possibly from infura's servers, etc.

It's possible you've exceeding the request rate limit they allow.

You can try to register and get a key with a higher limit, connect to a node not using infura, but ideally start your own, local node. It'll also be much faster.

Comment: I don't think it is the case, because firstly I do not use Infura, and secondly, as I mentioned above, I tried with several different -enterprise- providers.

Comment: CloudFlare is very wide used, it's possible that all of them use them